# R Regex, get string between quotations marks

Tags: python, r, regex

So. I'm trying to extract the `Document is original` from the string below.

```
c:1:{s:7:"note";s:335:"Document is original-no need to register again";}
```

Comment: I don't see any "Document not original"  in the example.

Comment: And the word "note" is also between question marks. How should the regular expression work exactly?

Comment: I see the answer has been already submitted. Next time please share your code so we know what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thoughts:

A little bit of work, get most components of that structure:

```r
string <- 'c:1:{s:7:"note";s:335:"Document is original-no need to register again";}'

strcapture("(.*):(.*):(.*)",
           strsplit(regmatches(string, gregexpr('(?<={)[^}]+(?=})', string, perl = TRUE))[[1]], ";")[[1]],
           proto = list(s="", len=1L, x=""))
#   s len                                                x
# 1 s   7                                           "note"
# 2 s 335 "Document is original-no need to register again"
```

A simpler approach, perhaps a little more hard-coded:

```r
regmatches(string, gregexpr('(?<=")([^;"]+)(?=")', string, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
# [1] "note"                                          
# [2] "Document is original-no need to register again"
```

From here, you need to figure out how to dismiss `"note"` and then perhaps `strsplit(.., "-")` to get the substring you want.